# Doxygen: Documenting overloaded functions

Tags: documentation, doxygen

In case I have my documentation separate from my code, how do I help Doxygen distinguish between overloaded functions (what to use in the `\fn` field)? A single function would be documented like this:

```
void func() {
}

/**
    \fn func
    \details Description here.
  */
```

What if I have two functions called `func`?

```
void func() {
}

void func(int i) {
}

/**
    \fn [What goes here?]
    \details Description here.
  */
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply document each overload as if it is a separate method (which it is, really :-) - just put the entire method signature in the \fn command instead of just the method's name. As in:

```
/**
    \fn func()
    \details Description here.
 */
void func() { }

/**
    \fn func(int i)
    \details Description here.
 */
void func(int i) { }
```

(Sorry, I just had to move the doc comments above the methods where they belong :-)

And indeed, you don't need the \fn command at all, if the comment is directly ahead of the code element it pertains to.

```
/**
    \details Description here.
 */
void func() { }

/**
    \details Description here.
 */
void func(int i) { }
```

Answer (score 21):

There is an \overload doxygen command for such cases. See [the doxygen command reference](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdoverload). Use your regular \fn command for the base case and use \overload for any, well, overload. :)